# Determine if a class implements a very specific interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, interface

There are tons of questions about this topic, but I have a slightly altered version of it.

We have the following code:

```
interface IFoo { }
interface IBar : IFoo { }
class Foo : IFoo { }
class Bar : IBar { }

bool Implements_IFoo(Type type) { /* ??? */ }
```

Now, the twist of the story: the method `Implements_IFoo` should only return true when the Type implements IFoo only and not any of the interfaces derived from IFoo. To illustrate here are some examples of this method:

```
Implements_IFoo(typeof(Foo)); // Should return true

Implements_IFoo(typeof(Bar)); // Should return false as Bar type 
                              // implements an interface derived from IFoo
```

Note that there can be numerous interfaces derived from IFoo and you do not necessarily know about their existence.

The obvious method is to find all interfaces derived from IFoo through reflection and then just check the typeof(Bar).GetInterfaces() is any of those are present in there. But I was wondering if someone can come up with a more elegant solution.

PS The question originates from some code I found that uses this check on classes (`if(obj.GetType() == typeof(BaseClass)) { ... }`). We are replacing classes with interfaces now that particular code. Also, just in case - I am implementing this check as a boolean flag, so this question is purely hypothetical.

Comment: I am really curious why you need this kind of introspection in the first place. Chances are your design is wrong.

Comment: Please read the question 'till the end before commenting next time - I already explained that this is a hypothetical question ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a try because it sounded like fun, and this works for your example:

```
bool ImplementsIFooDirectly(Type t) {
    if (t.BaseType != null && ImplementsIFooDirectly(t.BaseType)) { 
        return false; 
    }
    foreach (var intf in t.GetInterfaces()) {
        if (ImplementsIFooDirectly(intf)) { 
            return false;
        }
    }
    return t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(IFoo));
}
```

results:

```
ImplementsIFooDirectly(typeof(IFoo)); // false
ImplementsIFooDirectly(typeof(Bar)); // false
ImplementsIFooDirectly(typeof(Foo)); // true
ImplementsIFooDirectly(typeof(IBar)); // true
```

It doesn't look for all interfaces derived from `IFoo`, it just travels up the inheritance / interface implementation chain and see if `IFoo` is present at any level other than the exact level of the type.

It also detects if the interface is inherited via base type. Not sure if that is what you want.

Still, as others have said already, if this is really a requirement for you, then you might have a problem with your design. (EDIT: Just noticed your question is purely hypothetical. Then it's fine of course :))

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I meant. Marking your answer as correct since it was the first correct one. :)

Answer (score 3):

See the following site for examples on how this can be implemented;

[C# is keyword usage](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpIs.aspx)

Essentially you can use the 'is' keyword to determine whether the object inhabits a class type as part of it's class inheritance stack.

```
class Director  : Owner { }
class Developer : Employee { }
..
var dave = new Developer();
var steve = new Director();
var isEmployee = dave is Employee; // true
var isAlsoEmploye = steve is Employee; // false
```

In line with your example function:

```
bool Implements_Type(object instance, Type type) { 
return instance is type;
}
```

Comment: I know the `is` keyword and it does not solve the problem. Please see the part of my question with the examples. Note that IBar is derived from IFoo. Thus Bar also implements it through IBar. `is` will return true for expr. `Bar is IFoo` but that is not the desired outcome.

Answer (score 2):

```
static bool Implements_IFoo(Type type)
{
  if (typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(type.BaseType))
    return false;

  var barInterfaces = type.GetInterfaces()
    .Where(iface => typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(iface))
    .ToArray();

  return barInterfaces.Length > 0 
     && barInterfaces.Length == barInterfaces.Count(iface => iface == typeof(IFoo));
}
static bool Implements_IFoo_Optimized(Type type)
{
  if (typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(type.BaseType))
    return false;

  return type.GetInterfaces()
    .Where(iface => typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(iface))
    .Count() == 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
 public bool ImplementsIFooOnly(Type type)
 {
     return !type.GetInterfaces().Any(t => 
              { 
                   return t is IFoo && !t.Equals(typeof(IFoo)); 
              });
 }
```

There are probably more efficient ways.

Comment: I guess you meant `typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(t)` instead of `t is IFoo`, but yes, this is the stuff :)

Comment: And just in case - that code does not check base classes (well, that was not clearly defined in my question) and the condition when a type does not have any interfaces (=> `.Any(..)` returns false then).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the keyword [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

BTW in general, if you have a logical case where some class needs to be of type of some base class but not one of the inheritors, it's probably wrong OO design, one that might violate the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: Again, `is` is not helping as it will return `true` for expr. `Bar is IFoo` (and the desired output is `false` as Bar implements IFoo 'through' IBar). And if you cared to read the question thoroughly you would not have to bother mentioning Liskov and OO design. Keyword: hypothetical / theoretical. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Type class has a method called GetInterface you can use.

```
    bool Implements_IFoo(Type t)
    {
        return t.GetInterface(typeof(IFoo).Name) != null;
    }
```

Comment: Which checks all interfaces in the entire hierarchy, and so fails the second use case `Implements_IFoo(typeof(Bar));`